# Syntax for string.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex]) displays comma inside a square bracket?

Tags: javascript, mozilla

About the syntax mentioned in the website
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

They have mentioned the syntax for indexOf like this

> string.indexOf(searchValue**[**, fromIndex**]**)

where the comma is in between the sqaure brackets, but when we use the function the value is entered is after the comma.

Is this a kind of standard methodology for showing the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly standard. Items appearing inside `[]` brackets are optional. If you're not going to provide the second parameter, then you don't supply the comma either.

You wouldn't write `indexOf('abc',);`